# Ruby on Rails - Doing addition in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'm brand new to Rails. I have a simple golf app that you can track you score on each hole.  I want to calculate the total score for each game.  I currently have this code in the view (which works just fine):

```
<td><%= game.hole_1 + game.hole_2 + game.hole_3 + game.hole_4 + game.hole_5 + game.hole_6 + game.hole_7 + game.hole_8 + game.hole_9 + game.hole_10.to_i + game.hole_11.to_i + game.hole_12.to_i + game.hole_13.to_i + game.hole_14.to_i + game.hole_15.to_i + game.hole_16.to_i + game.hole_17.to_i + game.hole_10.to_i %></td>
```

I know this isn't the rails way so I was wondering how I would put this logic into the model so that I can write `<%= game.score %>` in the view

Comment: Why do you have `.to_i` for some holes and not for other holes? However, the idea is, you can define a `score` method in your `Game` model where you can add all the holes of the `Game` model. Then, from view, you can just call `game.score` on the `game` object.

Comment: Why do you have one extra column for each hole? Why not store them in a separate table? That would help you avoid the hidden duplicate of hole 10 as well.

Comment: I think you meant to write `hole_18` instead of `hole_10` again at the end and got a typo in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, define a method `score`:

```
def score
  self.hole_1 + self.hole_2 + self.hole_3 + self.hole_4 + self.hole_5 +
      self.hole_6 + self.hole_7 + self.hole_8 + self.hole_9 +
      self.hole_10.to_i + self.hole_11.to_i + self.hole_12.to_i +
      self.hole_13.to_i + self.hole_14.to_i + self.hole_15.to_i +
      self.hole_16.to_i + self.hole_17.to_i + self.hole_10.to_i
end
```

Then, in your view, just call that `score` method on a `Game` object:

```
<%= game.score %>
```

Comment: Yeah, I would consider having separate tables for them as well. But, I tried to keep my answer as short as possible and as much aligned with the OP as possible. Thanks for pointing that :)